# .gitignore not ignoring package.json

Tags: git, gruntjs, gitignore

I have a node project and I am trying to ignore my package.json.

I have added package.json inside .gitignore.

Basically I am working on creating swimlanes and I have another project's package.json overwritting the existing project's package.json.

What i see happening is the package.json file is overwritting the existing and its not ignoring the new package.json althought its in the .gitignore.

I tried

```
git rm --cached
```

and

```
git add .
```

But this is deleteing my package.json file from my local which I dont want

Expected: I need the package.json to be igniored when I pull the new package.json using grunt fetchFromArtifactory.

Answer (score 7):

If you already are tracking a file, you can't add it to `.gitignore`. Then git will start to track that file changes.

You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository/11366713#11366713) to how to tell git to ignore changes in a tracked file.